# Is there a difference between slices and list?

Tags: go

Is there a difference in go between slices and list.

What I understood is there are array (fixed size) and slices (dynamic size), but is there a difference between these 2 things:

```
var slice []int
list := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
```

I would like to say they are both slices but am I correct?

Comment: One is a slice of int and one a slice of string. There is no `list` in golang.

Comment: Both of these are slices. Golang doesn't have `list` data structure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var slice []int
list := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
```

Both of these are slices.

It is an array only if size is mentioned in declaration. This size cannot be changed later, therefore it is of fixed size.

```
var array [5]int
array2 := [3]string{"a","b","c"}
```

[Go Slices & Arrays](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

Understanding the difference between arrays and slices is easier when you look at their internal representations.

**Array:**

Array is a list of values laid out sequentially in memory.

array := [4]int{1,2,3,4}

```
       +-----------------------+
[4]int |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |
       +-----------------------+
```

Once you have defined an array, it's size cannot be changed. The `[4]int` here will always remain an array of 4 integers. `[4]int` and `[5]int` are incompatible types.

**Slice:**

The slice type is an abstraction built on top of Go's array type. It is a descriptor of a segment of an array.

It consists of 3 components

1. ptr - a pointer to the underlying array,
2. len - the length of the segment,
3. cap - and, its capacity (the maximum length of the segment).

   ```
          +-----+
    []int | ptr |
          +-----+
          | len |
          +-----+
          | cap |
          +-----+
             |
             |
          +-----------------------+
   [4]int |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |
          +-----------------------+
   ```

The slice can be modified to point to a different array of same or 
different size. Hence, the slice has dynamic size.

```
 slice1 := []int{1,2,3} 

       +-----------------+
slice1 | ptr |  3  |  3  | 
       +-----------------+

 slice1  = []int{1,2}

       +-----------------+
slice1 | ptr |  2  |  2  | 
       +-----------------+
```

And, there can be more than one slice pointing to the same array.

Answer (score 1):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Slice types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types)
>
> A slice is a descriptor for a contiguous segment of an underlying
>   array and provides access to a numbered sequence of elements from that
>   array. A slice type denotes the set of all slices of arrays of its
>   element type. The value of an uninitialized slice is nil.
>
> ```
> SliceType = "[" "]" ElementType .
> ```

---

A Go slice is a slice of an underlying array. Go doesn't have lists. In Go, you can implement a list using a slice.

These are both Go slices. Neither is a list.

```
var intSlice []int
strSlice := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
```

`intSlice` is initialized to the zero value for a slice which is `nil`.  The elements of the underlying array.for `strSlice` are initialized to the  slice composite literal values `{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}`.